# GAE: How to use unicode characters in url

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, sqlite, url-routing

I've just upgraded GAE to 1.7.6 (python 2.7). My app uses some spanish characters in URLs (words such as "españa" or "cádiz"). Up to this moment, I've had no problems dealing with them. However, after upgrading, I keed having and error message and my app crashing wenever I introduce special characters in my url:

```
ProgrammingError('You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
req.respond()
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
self.server.gateway(self).respond()
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 230, in __call__
return app(environ, start_response)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/server.py", line 1114, in __call__
return self._handle_request(environ, start_response)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/server.py", line 512, in _handle_request
http_version=http_version)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub.py", line 160, in WrappedMethod
return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/logservice/logservice_stub.py", line 151, in start_request
host, start_time, method, resource, http_version))
ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
```

I've written a simple app to debug the problem, with no positive results:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello world!')

class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self, param):
    self.response.write(param)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/(.*)', MyHandler)
], debug=True)
```

When visiting the URL "/hola" the response is as expected, and the browser displays the "hola" word. However, when visiting "/españa" or even "/espa%C3%B1a" the Development server crashes with the error shown above.

Note that the error only occurs in development, and I guess it's related with the new sqlite database; however, in the previous example, I'm not using the database at all!

Any ideas? Please, help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bug with dev server. Best thing for now is to star the bug on GAE bug tracker: [GAE bug - url's with unicode characters](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9040).

Hopefully they will solve this issue faster if more people "star" it.